# How can I add a warehouse location to a Shopify confirmation email?

Tags: email, templates, location, show

In the Shopify backend I have set up 3 locations: New Zealand, UK, and US. The customer orders an item from a particular country, and the order detail page in the admin console shows the location. However, the administrator also wants to see that location in the order confirmation email.

[See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdm28.png)

I have added the following code to the template of the new order email:

```
<strong>Location</strong>
<br/><span>{{order.location}}</span>
<br/><span>{{ shipping_address.country }}</span>
```

Also used a shipping address country (an alternative option but not a perfect solution.)

How can I add the part of the screenshot that I have marked with a red square (i.e. the location value) to the email template?

Answer (score 0):

The "fulfillment locations" don't seem to be accessible from the email template, based on the [Notification variables reference](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/orders/notifications/email-variables).

I believe you would need to access the [FulfillmentOrder.assignedLocation field](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2022-10/objects/FulfillmentOrder#field-fulfillmentorder-assignedlocation), but there can be multiple Fulfillment Orders per Order and as I said, there doesn't seem to be a way to get to them from an email template.

Perhaps the [Order Automator app](https://apps.shopify.com/order-automator) can be of use, either out of the box or they also develop customizations when needed.